# pycurl.error: (35, 'gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed')

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, curl

On trying to download from a `https://` URL with PycURL `'PycURL/7.19.3 libcurl/7.35.0 GnuTLS/2.12.23 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3'` in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.2, I receive

```
pycurl.error: (35, 'gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed')
```

`curl`, however, works fine, maybe due to the fact that it is using `openssl`:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
```

So I would prefer a PycURL binding to `openssl` too. I tried to reinstall `python-pycurl` with

```
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
sudo apt-get remove python-pycurl
sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
```

as is frequenty advised on similar questions, but still `pycurl` is nor bound to `openssl`. Same with `apt-get remove` and `easy_install` etc.

Question: How to get a PycURL with `openssl` binding?

Bonus-question: Why is PycURL not installed with `openssl` binding right away, because the GnuTLS binding seems not to work anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was sincerely hoping that this could be resolved without following some instructions which I hardly understand and compiling things and so on. But unfortunately...

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/aerickson/f15133a7e56b2d7f27e3) from 2014 for instructions.

At the time of writing, using Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.2 LTS, the versions are still the same, namely `7.19.3`, so the instructions in the Gist can be followed one by one. Spot check was ok and also curl is still working with `https://`. After stepping through the recipe, `pycurl.version` shows

```
PycURL/7.19.3 libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
```

To automate the downloading, patching and compiling, you will love this little script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
#   How to rebuild PycURL against OpenSSL on Ubuntu
#   (tested for 14.04.2 now)
#
#   This script implements the great Gist by aerickson:
#   https://gist.github.com/aerickson/f15133a7e56b2d7f27e3
#   feel free to use it anyway you like.
#   Credits go to Andrew anyway :)
#


# we will add some colored headers that make it easier to find obstacles 
# in the terminal output (which will be > 1000 lines...)
ESC="\x1b["
RESET=$ESC"39;49;00m"
RED=$ESC"31;01m"
GREEN=$ESC"32;01m"
YELLOW=$ESC"33;01m"
BLUE=$ESC"34;01m"

header() {
    echo -e "\n$YELLOW --- $1 --- $RESET\n"
}

echo -e "\n\n$GREEN"
echo -e "\
Build pycurl with openssl support\n\n\
Section numbers refer to\n\
https://gist.github.com/aerickson/f15133a7e56b2d7f27e3
"
echo -e "$RESET\n"



# remove eventually existing pycurl
header "0. remove python-pycurl"
sudo apt-get remove python-pycurl --yes

header "1. install build essentials"
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev --yes

header "2./3. make build dir"
mkdir ~/python-pycurl-openssl
cd ~/python-pycurl-openssl

if [ ! "$HOME/python-pycurl-openssl" = `pwd` ]; then
    echo -e "\n${RED}Cannot change to working dir. WTF?${RESET}\n"
    exit 1
fi

header "4. get pycurl sources"
sudo apt-get source python-pycurl --yes

header "5. get build dependencies for python-pycurl"
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pycurl --yes

header "6. install libcurl with openssl"
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev --yes

DIR=`find * -name 'pycurl*' -type d -print`
DSC=`find * -name '*.dsc' -type f -print`

echo
echo "DIR = $DIR"
echo "DSC = $DSC"
echo

header "7. unpack source archive"
sudo dpkg-source -x $DSC

header "8. change to package dir"
cd $DIR

header "9. edit debian/control file"
sudo cp debian/control ./control.gnutls
sudo cat ./control.gnutls | sed -e 's|libcurl4-gnutls-dev|libcurl4-openssl-dev|' | sudo tee ./control.openssl >/dev/null
sudo cp ./control.openssl debian/control

header "10. build package"
echo "hold on..."
echo "(crashdump of nosetests is 'normal')"
sudo PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b 2>&1 | sudo tee ../buildlog.txt >/dev/null
echo
echo -e $BLUE
sudo head ../buildlog.txt
echo -e $RESET
echo "   [ ... 1000+ more messages omitted ... ]"
echo -e $BLUE
sudo tail ../buildlog.txt
echo -e $RESET
echo
echo "find more output in ~/python-pycurl-openssl/buildlog.txt:"
wc -l  ../buildlog.txt

header "11. install via package manager"
sudo dpkg -i ../python-pycurl_*.deb

echo
echo "some other packages are available also now:"
ls ../*.deb
echo "they can be installed by 'sudo dpkg -i ../py...' from here."
```

There is hope, however, that a newer version `7.19.5` will make it to the repos, which [is supposed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pycurl/+bug/1111673) to have the issues fixed in GnuTLS so that PycURL would start to work out of the box. Still the question remains, why this issue is in the repos [since 2009](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=515200) and no one cares...

**Update Issues**

Funny enough, any subsequent regular Ubuntu update of pycurl/libcurl will overwrite your change. So be prepared to repeat this over and over :(

Alternatively, you can put `python-pycurl` on hold **after** building it with `openssl` to make sure `apt-get update` will not overwrite it anymore:

```
sudo apt-mark hold python-pycurl
```

Updates can be re-enabled later by

```
sudo apt-mark unhold python-pycurl
```

**Raspberry Recipe**

The above script runs fine on Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Wheezy too, when you add the ability to install sources before by

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and uncommenting the `deb-src` line, so that the file will look like

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

When the sources are not found (in step 4), you might have to do an

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before running the above script.

Note: On the Raspberry, the process suffers a bit from the processor speed and you should take aside half an hour (if everything works smoothly). And again, either you put `python-pycurl` on hold or you will have to invest this half hour again after each update.

Comment: The handshake failure appeared for me when running `add-apt-repository`. The solution here built `pycurl`, but removed `add-apt-repository`. Reinstalling `add-apt-repository` removed the newly compiled `pycurl` :/